# render a div's height according to the rendered height of anoother div

Tags: css, html

i have made [this sample on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kBqJZ/1/).

I don't want the Div B to go out div A. For that the `overflow:hidden` property is not working becase altough div B is inside div A but because of z-index & absolute positioning is not behaving as a child of div A. The problem is div A adjusts itself to content. And I need to make\appear div B not out of Div A.

Any suggestions ???

p.s i could use javascript or server-side code\script to adjust height of B but isn't there another solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to put position relative to your parent div.

```
.aaa
{
    float: left;    
    width: 950px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.7);
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
}
```

Position absolute won't work if the parent div is not in position relative

Comment: [A note] using `bottom: 0` instead of `height: 100%` in `.bbb` class also works. (well keeping position: relative to the parent container as mentioned in above solution)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".aaa").height($(".bbb").height()+38);
});
```

put this code and include jquery in your project. In this case you are not manipulating height of b div. but you are manipulating of a div.